# Declaring Jmockit mock parameters on @BeforeMethod of TestNG

Tags: java, testng, jmockit

I've been testing my code behavior using `TestNG` and `JMockit` for a while now and I have had no specific issue with their combination. Today I came across a situation where I needed to  mock one of my internal dependencies, in the so called, *type wide manner* and I did not need to keep that mock around since none of the test cases dealt with it directly while they counted on the mocked version functionality. So, naturally, I put the mocking logic in my `@BeforeMethod`. Here is a sample:

```
public class SampleTest
{
    @Mocked
    @Cascading
    private InnerDependency dependency;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod()
    {
        new NonStrictExpectations()
        {
            {
                dependency.getOutputStream((String)any);
                result = new Delegate<OutputStream>()
                {
                    public OutputStream getOutputStream(String url)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testNormalOperation()
    {
        // The test whose desired behavior depends on dependency being mocked out
        // ..
    }
}
```

But, since my tests do not care about the mocked `dependency` explicitly, I'm not willing to declare it as a test class field, unlike what is done above. To my knowledge of `JMockit` The only options remaining would be:

1. Declare `dependency` as a local mock field:

   ```
   new NonStrictExpectations()
   {
       @Cascading
       private InnerDependency dependency;
       {
           //...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Declare `dependency` as an input argument for `beforeMethod()`, similar to what is done for normal `@Test` methods:

   ```
   @BeforeMethod
   public void beforeMethod(@Mocked @Cascading final InnerDependency dependency)
   {
      // ...
   }
   ```

I see that **JMockit 1.6+**  would not like the first option and warns with `WARNING: Local mock field "dependency" should be moved to the test class or converted to a parameter of the test method`. Hence, to keep everyone happy, I'm ruling this option out.

But for the second option, `TestNG` (currently 6.8.6) throws exception when running the test saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`. I don't see this behavior with normal `@Test` cases passed with `@Mocked` parameters. Even playing with `@Parameter` and `@Optional` will not help (and should not have!).

So, is there any way I could make this work without declaring the *unneccessary test class mock field*, or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only test methods (annotated with `@Test` in JUnit or TestNG) support mock parameters, so the only choice here is to declare a mock field at the test class level.

Even if not used in any test method, I think it's better than having it declared in a setup  method (using `@Before`, `@BeforeMethod`, etc.). If it were to be possible, the mock would still have to apply to *all* tests, because of the nature of setup methods; having a mock field of the test class makes it clear what the scope of the mock is.

Comment: Is this a limitation of TestNG? Can this be a feature for JMockit in future?

Comment: No, it's a design choice in JMockit.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic partial mocking](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#dynamicPartial) is one more technique to specify @Mocked dependencies locally. However, it has it's limitations (see comments below).

Comment: Well, Dynamic Partial Mocking can be used, but as the documentation states it has limitations: `If the Class object for a given class is passed, the methods and constructors defined in that class are considered for mocking, but not the methods and constructors of its super-classes.` In my case, I do not have access to the inner dependency to have it injected (it is way buried deep) and going with the class type does not provide what I need, either.

Comment: Would passing an instance suit you? `If an instance of a given class is passed, then all methods defined in the whole class hierarchy, from the concrete class of the given instance up to (but not including) Object, are considered for mocking; the constructors of these classes, however, are not (since an instance was already created).`